# Sony Xperia Z3 D6446 Touchscreen not working right on bottom

Tags: touchscreen, screen-resolution, sony-xperia-z3

My xperia touchscreen got physically broken. I got it to a "tech service" so they promised to use an original piece and change the old damaged display with a new display.

After they changed (many other hardware things like camera button and gsm antenna where damaged), the touchscreen aparently works ok, but, I noticed that, until I tap closer to the bottom of the screen, my taps get misplaced. I can verify it with the developer options.

I tried changing the resolution, density and overscan via adb shell with multiple values, but the effect is almost the same, it seems the installed  display doesn't have the right behavior.

I've tried like 20+ touchscreen calibrator applications (like 3 different languages) to solve this problem, and still persists.

I restored to factory, installed custom external ROMs, even installed ISP custom ROMs and nothing worked.

I've run the test for the touchscreen and I can use all the screen without a lose.

Hope someone can lead me to a possible solution, maybe a way I can play with those 3 values so I can "emulate" the correct position of my taps. Ideally, a way to "not enlarge my taps" while I get closer to the botttom of the screen.

Comment: It simply sounds like you need another hardware replacement...

Comment: Well, I tried all the possible solutions via software, and finally I've decided to throw it at technicians face for breaking the touchscreen, there was no other option. Thanks.